# Why doesn't my python pandas code shows a table?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am using Spyder and the following source code:

```
import pandas as pd


filename = "file.csv" # 5.35 GB in size

df = pd.read_csv(filename, nrows=5)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

df
```

**Output**

```
runfile('C:/Users/pc/Desktop/Data Mining/file.py', wdir='C:/Users/pc/Desktop/Data Mining/')
Reloaded modules: jupyter_client.session, zmq.eventloop, zmq.eventloop.ioloop, 
tornado.platform, tornado.platform.asyncio, tornado.gen, zmq.eventloop.zmqstream, 
jupyter_client.jsonutil, jupyter_client.adapter, spyder, spyder.pil_patch, PIL, 
PIL._version, PIL.Image, PIL.ImageMode, PIL.TiffTags, PIL._binary, PIL._util, PIL._imaging, 
cffi, cffi.api, cffi.lock, cffi.error, cffi.model
```

Why doesn't my python pandas code show a table?

---

Also, after using print`(df)` :

```
import pandas as pd


filename = "clash_royale_games_Jan_2019.csv"


df = pd.read_csv(filename, nrows=5)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
runfile('C:/Users/pc/Desktop/Data Mining/file.py', wdir='C:/Users/pc/Desktop/Data Mining/')
Reloaded modules: jupyter_client.session, zmq.eventloop, zmq.eventloop.ioloop, tornado.platform, tornado.platform.asyncio, tornado.gen, zmq.eventloop.zmqstream, jupyter_client.jsonutil, jupyter_client.adapter, spyder, spyder.pil_patch, PIL, PIL._version, PIL.Image, PIL.ImageMode, PIL.TiffTags, PIL._binary, PIL._util, PIL._imaging, cffi, cffi.api, cffi.lock, cffi.error, cffi.model
              timestamp  arena_id  has_won        tag  \
0  2018-12-31T23:00:46Z        16        1  289VVL288   
1  2018-12-31T23:01:34Z        14        1  2G0PRYVRU   
2  2018-12-31T23:02:00Z        13        1   92GLVGQU   
3  2018-12-31T23:02:00Z        14        1  2Y28RPJRC   
4  2018-12-31T23:02:02Z        16        0    8RYLV2R   

                                         player_deck  
0  elixir-collector_golem_mega-knight_mega-minion...  
1  dark-prince_goblin-gang_miner_pekka_the-log_to...  
2  baby-dragon_balloon_barbarian-barrel_bowler_fr...  
3  baby-dragon_fireball_inferno-dragon_mega-minio...  
4  archers_barbarian-barrel_goblins_hog-rider_kni...
```

You see the 5th column is truncated.

How can I show the 5th column in full?

Comment: do you have to use spyder? jupyter notebooks gets around this easily - and you can set column widths etc.. (which to be fair may not be a function of using jupyter; i've only ever used jupyter or vs-code which don't have this issue)

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` display options are in `pd.options.display`. Setting `pd.options.display.max_colwidth` and possibly `pd.options.display.width` to higher values should fix the truncation.

Your first block doesn't display anything because you aren't telling it to. Tools like IPython and Jupyter will show the `__repr__` of the last object in a cell, but that's specific to those platforms, and Spyder is basically just running your files as a regular Python script.